# Disabling SSLv2 on Dovecot v1

Tags: ssl, dovecot, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I'm still using Dovecot v1 (1.1.20) on an osx server.  I'm trying to disable SSLv2. Seem like the default config already disabled it:

`ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL`

But when I test my web server with ssllabs, it complaints my mail server (pop, imap) is vulnerable because of the use of SSLv2 (same key). I also tried:

`ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!SSLv2`

With no more success.

I know, this server need major software update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSLv2 is a *protocol*, not a cipher. The "SSLv2" in the cipher list represents several ciphers associated with SSLv2, not the protocol itself.

In dovecot, the undocumented parameter `ssl_protocols` is used to disable particular protocols:

```
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
```

This exists in Dovecot v2; but I don't know if it exists in Dovecot v1.

Comment: This parameter doesn't exist in Dovecot v1.

Comment: I think you're out of luck, then.

Comment: I think you are right. Short term fix is to use a dedicated ssl certificate to avoid drown contamination of others servers.